# Use nlp to answer a customized question in a large corpus

Tags: nlp

Say I have a corpus in a company's annual report showing their revenue data of 4 industries: automotive, semi-conductor, green energy, and healthcare. For humans it is not hard to find the revenue data for one specific industry. If I were to use NLP to automate it so i do not have to read it, is it possible that NLP can match the correct revenue data to one specific industry?

I used NLP for sentiment analysis, topic modeling and text generation. But none of these seems to be relevant to the application above. Any ideas? What function in what library can I use?

Comment: I have done something similar and I think it's possible, you could use an AI to classify and identify specific sentences in which they are talking about some industry, then with NLP you look for the figures inside the sentence. The classification part requires many samples of sentences related to the industry, if you do not have samples you will have to use keywords to select them.

Comment: I can only think of using concordance in nltk to extract where one industry is mentioned, but do not know how to match the number

Comment: try to look for spacy entity detection.

Answer (score 1):

It will be relatively easy to comment if the questioner posts some sample text for each of the 4 classes, namely automotive, semi-conductor, green energy, and healthcare. Nonetheless, the author attempts to provide an approach that works in theory.

---

Let us attempt to understand the problem from NLP perspective as given below.

1. There are documents which are made up of some content. Each document could be a financial statement or something with text and corresponding facts.
2. Each document is expected to have content relevant to one class i.e automative, semi-conductor etc.,
3. There is a non-zero probability that the content of one class could overlap with another. For example, content around green energy may have some mentions of low emission automotives.

An approach to identify similar content could be made as follows. These steps are taken from another answer from the author [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/71512/nlp-simple-approach-to-identify-commonalities-in-text-comments-between-people/72060#72060).

1. **Step 1** Deploy a *cosine similarity* algorithm to measure the similarity between content from multiple documents. In order to bring it a step closer to semantic similarity, use **WORDNET** to build the features for computing *cosine similarity*. This will ensure that tokens such as "path" are treated closer to token "road".
2. **Step 2** Group content from different documents beyond a threshold cosine value (example: 0.75) as documents from same class.
3. **Step 3** Manually inspect the different groups to see if the content from same class is grouped into one group. If there is a mix of more than one class in these groups, refine the cosine similarity by feature engineering. For example, add TfIDf to drop less informative features.
4. **Step 4** Based on the outcome of *Step 3*, deploy more feature engineering until the groups are homogenous.
5. **Step 5** Once the grouping seems homogenous, one could deploy Information Retrieval techniques to retrieve information. This step is arguably the most difficult of all the steps listed above and the author at the time of writing this content does not have any working knowledge of IE/IR techniques.